# Upload file using jQuery reading from local

Tags: jquery, node.js, upload, blob

I'm trying to upload file using jQuery in pure js, reading file from local path

The canonical way is to get the file from the html input appending to FormData

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("test", " [69]");
form.append("file", fileInput.files[0], "/C:/test.txt");

var settings = {
  "url": "https://...",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "processData": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "contentType": false,
  "data": form
};
```

But I need to read the file on demand without using an html interface.
How can I read this file and put it into a blob mantaining/getting the MIME type?
I've tryed this whitout success:

```
const fd = fs.openSync(path, 'r');
const stat = fs.statSync(path);
const bytecount = stat.size;
const buf = Buffer.alloc(bytecount)
fs.readSync(fd, buf, 0, bytecount, 0);
const  file = new Blob([buf]);
// I have to get the real MIME type
//const file2 = file.slice(0, file.size, "text/plain")
formData.append('file', file2, 'blob');
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I doubt you will be able to do this due to security protections in the Browser. The browser will prevent the reading of a Local file without User interaction. You can open a Relative Path, to the script. You can open an HTTP or HTTPS path, yet reading files from the local file system requires the user to "Open" the file or browse it with the Input button.

Comment: Thank you!
I was wandering that you could not possible due to security protection.
Anyway I didn't specify that I'm working with an electron app, so my browser is also working on local machine. This permits to the js part to read directly the file from the disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript FileReader
Do this

```
const htmlFileElem = document.querySelector('whatever')
htmlFileElem.onChange = function(e) {
const reader = new FileReader()
reader.onload = function(e) {
console.log(e)
// get the file blob format
const file_blob = e.target.result
}
reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]) // note for a single file
// to get the mime type do this
const mime_type = e.target.files[0].type
}
```

I hope this is what you're looking for and it also helps

or do this

```
fetch(url_to_remote_file)
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(blob => {
 console.log(blob) // you will see things you need here
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! 
But also this solution assume that whe fiel il managed ad uploaded from the browser.
Anyway I didn't specify that I'm working with an electron app, so my browser is also working on local machine. This permits the js part to read directly the file from the disk.
Is it possible to use FileReader to read file from disk and put in the Blob. I've tryed also this way, maybe I forget something in the middle

Comment: Did it work after you tried my solution?, and it is possible to use FileReader to real file from disk if FileReader is supported in the local webview and you can simply use fetch, fetch will work fine even if FileReader is not supported but also Fetch doesn't work on older version of webview, if  fetch is not available in the webview then use XMLHttpRequest, but Fecth should work great

Comment: Hi Paulos,
I've just tried your solution with fech and it works!!
Thanks you!!
Now I'm try to understand why the blob created seems to be non completed or not suitable for the server side.

Comment: the blob created by fetch right??

Comment: Yes, the Blob is created by the fetch and has any other modification.